# Is it correct and formal to use "ones" in this sentence..?

Tags: word-usage

Ions follow Hofmeister series and “salting out” effect is more significant of anions than cations and multivalent salts than monovalent *ones*.

Thank you for your opinion and help. :)

Comment: I would write "more significant for" and repeat "salts" instead of "ones" for greater clarity.

Comment: My suggestions: Ions follow **the** Hofmeister series, and **the** “salting out” effect is more significant **for** anions than cations, and **for** multivalent salts than monovalent ones. (note punctuation)

Answer (score 1):

Ones in this sentence is taking the role of a pronoun demonstrating the difference between two salts. Although, its not incorrect, I personally would say "monovalent salts" as opposed to "monovalent ones" for clarity.

Comment: And fix the other errors as well.